# Мех и мешок

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Всегда считала, что мех (сшитая из шкур животных емкость для жидкости) назван так именно из-за того, что сделан из шкур, то есть, из меха. Но потом прочитала, что "мех" и "мешок" - родственные слова.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: какое слово было изначально и есть ли связь между мехом животных, мехом для воды и мешком?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что такое мешок? Не менее важную роль играет также и анализ тех формальных средств (например, приставки, суффиксы), с помощью которых образовано слово (словообразовательный анализ). Допустим, что мы хотим выяснить, каково было происхождение слова мешок. Выделяем в этом слове суффикс -ок (-ек). Находим ряд русских слов с тем же самым суффиксом, которые с полной очевидностью соотносятся с простыми бессуффиксными образованиями: порошок - порох, посошок - посох, вершок - верх, смешок - смех, грешок - грех, душок - дух, пушок - пух и т. п. Если в этот же самый "словообразовательный ряд" включить слово мешок, то его можно будет соотнести со словом мех. Таким образом, словообразовательный анализ позволил нам прояснить этимологию слова мешок. Правда, здесь, быть может, последует возражение: кто же изготовляет мешки из меха?! Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, обратимся к истории. В древности "мешки" (мехи) изготовляли из шкур животных. В этих мехах обычно держали вино и другие продук-ты. Хорошо известно, например, выражение из Евангелия: "Не вливают вина молодого в мехи ветхие". Древние ассирийские воины переправлялись через ши-рокие реки вплавь с полным вооружением, пользуясь при этом надутыми воздухом мехами (мешками из шкур). Да и в наши дни такие мехи для хранения жидкости и для переправы через реки употребляются многими народами Востока. По-русски такой мешок, изготовленный из цельной шкуры, называется бурдюком (это слово было заимствовано из азербайджанского языка). (Ю.Откупщиков К истокам слова)

Answer (score 0):

Наверно,  сначала  мешок  это  небольшой  мех,  а  затем  что-либо  функционально  схожее,  но  из  ткани.  Мех  для  жидкостей  не  сшивали,  это  была  одна  особым  образом  снятая  шкура.

Answer (score 0):

Почему это только для жидкости? Для любых товаров, типа, багажная караванная емкость. ***На юге и западе мешок для поклажи зовут мехом. В.Даль.*** А еще это - волынка, поддувальный снаряд для кузниц и оргАнов;- снятая целиком (дудкою) шкура, зашитая и обделанная для держанья жидкостей, бурдюк, саба, турсук; - выделанные на шубу и сшитые мешком либо в две полсти (половинки) шкуры пушного зверя; а изначально  - мех, умалит. мешок, звериная шкура, снятая с шерстью. Это всё у Даля.